# Blender 3.0 Asset Browser--Catalogs only available for files in current project?

Tags: interface, asset, asset-browser

I'm so happy about Blender 3.0's Asset Browser! I'm working on adding and organizing assets and while I think I understand most of it, whenever I try to move assets to a Catalog, I get the message, **Only assets from this current file can be moved between catalogs**. Is it correct then to conclude that catalogs only apply to assets in the current (opened) project file? Thanks. Blender 3.0.0 Windows 10

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G4DjNSxlxSM&t) is a good Asset Browser tutorial which was recorded back in June. I believe there's much more to come in Blender 3.1.

Comment: That’s a great video. If I understand correctly, catalogs can only be created with the resources loaded into the active blend file, but once created those catalogs are available across other blend files.

Comment: That's how it appears to work from the very brief look I've had  at it. There seem to be more YT videos appearing about it almost daily at the moment.

Comment: I think this comes from the fact that the link to a catalog is stored on the object, so you have to modify the source file containing the object in order to change its catalog

Answer (score 0):

it confused me too. the only way i can workaround this problem is
to append blend file with some object to opened current file with catalogs hierarchy than mark object as assets and add to some catalog. save the lib file. and voila have an asset in catalog / in lib file. (after all i can delete blend file with some object)